# Editable Columns Plugin -> Using Editable Select gives error

Tags: laravel-backpack

I have Two Models

- Inscriptions
- Fairs

Inscriptions should be inside Fair, so a $fillabe 'fair_id' is in the model Inscriptions

Fair has this two columns 'id' and 'name'

I wanted to use Editable Columns to edit the Fair directly in the List Page

so I added:

```php
...
use \Backpack\EditableColumns\Http\Controllers\Operations\MinorUpdateOperation;
...
    protected function setupListOperation()
    {
        // CRUD::column('fair')->label('Feria'); // This was before and worked right

        // editable_select
        CRUD::addColumn([
            'name'    => 'fair',
            'label'   => 'Feria',
            'type'    => 'editable_select',
            'options' => \App\Models\Fair::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray(),
        ]);
```

And when I enter in the List page it gives me the error:

**Object of class App\Models\Fair could not be converted to int**

Giving the error at: app/Http/Middleware/CheckIfAdmin.php: 66

Comment: I can't really tell what's happening from your error, sorry. Maybe this can help you debug it: If you pass an empty array to your `options` - does the error still happen? If not, then your problem is with the generated array. Try generating that same array somewhere isolated, see what the problem is. A good place to do that is inside Laravel Tinker. Visually the syntax looks ok to me... but sometimes one wrong letter can mess everything. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've just answered a question on our community forum similar to yours.

https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/community-forum/discussions/358

TLDR:

> Editable columns don't understand relationships like Backpack fields do.
> You should provide the database column name of the relationship

It's probably late and you figured it out already, but still hope it can help someone in the future.

Cheers